# how to concat 2 dataframes, keeping rows with same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

[image]I have 2 dataframes, that i want to concat with keeping the order of the column of df1:

```
df1:
index   unnamed:0   unnamed:1      unnamed:393    unnamed:395
 0       nan           1       ...     394           396 
 1       0            BB               CC            DD


df2:

    index     Service
     220      ABC
     222      ABB
     394      CC
     396      DD
     ....

the output should be like:
df3:

     index 
       0      394    396  
       1      394    396
       2      CC     DD
       3      CC     DD
```

if i simply make `df3=pd.concat([df1,df2])` it just adds df2 at the end of the list of df 1 as whole 
Almost same when using `df3=pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)`
i think there is some issue with multiindexing, but don't know what to type.
Thanks

Comment: The 2 dataframes are completely different. `concat` is an action meant to add similar/identical-format dataframes. What do you exactly want to achieve? What columns do you want to have, and what are the connections between the 2 dataframes?

Comment: @Aryerez want to add all the matches in one column each

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df1.join(df2)`.
This produces an outcome like this:
[image]
The documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).
For more information about all the kinds of merging operations in pandas, you can also check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).

Comment: Thanks, but ti should find the matches of each row and concat together in one columns(all the matches) . not next to each other

Comment: What you ask is not entirely clear for me, sorry. Can you explain it with the dataframes I provided in my image as an example?

Comment: I posted a picture above. Maybe it helps

Comment: I am not sure you can do this with a function from pandas but you can try with the different arguments provided.

Comment: maybe there is a function like lambda or stack, to make 2 columns as one and then concat?

Comment: lambda is not a function per se, it is an unnamed function that you can make it whatever you want